# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in my MapReduce code

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, mapper

Im trying to break the records into words based on non-alphanumeric characters, count the first letter in every word and get the total occurrence of first alphabet in each word. Below is the Mapper class logic I tried to execute.

```
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context ctx) {
    String line = value.toString();
    String[] split = line.split("\\W+");
    String firstChar;
    for(String words: split) {
        firstChar = String.valueOf(words.charAt(0));
        try {
            ctx.write(new Text(firstChar), new IntWritable(1));
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Error: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at com.hadoopexp.mapper.MapperClass.map(MapperClass.java:17)
    at com.hadoopexp.mapper.MapperClass.map(MapperClass.java:1)
```

But Im getting StringIndexOutOfBounds exception for this logic at the line:

```
firstChar = String.valueOf(words.charAt(0));
```

I have put some blank lines in the input file just to see if it works. (like below)

```
Liverpool
Manchester


London

Toronto ? ?? !!12 32
```

Can anyone help me on how to fix the logic. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting an empty string returns an array containing a single element of an empty string. I'd just check for it explicitly:

```
for(String words: split) {
    if (!words.isEmpty()) { // Here!
        firstChar = String.valueOf(words.charAt(0));
        try {
            ctx.write(new Text(firstChar), new IntWritable(1));
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```